# Slider not scrolling through image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slider

Having an issue with my responsive slider - was working perfectly fine but by removing my changes it still not scrolling through the images?

Here is my code (This is sitting in my header):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>


    <div style="heigt: 500px;">
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
           <li><img src="img/businessbig.jpg" alt="" ></li>
          <li><img src="img/cateringbig.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="img/nurseriesbig.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

This is sat at the bottom of the page:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>



    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
      });

      $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
      speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
      timeout: 4000,          // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
      pager: false,           // Boolean: Show pager, true or false
      nav: false,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
      random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
      pause: false,           // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
      pauseControls: true,    // Boolean: Pause when hovering controls, true or false
      prevText: "Previous",   // String: Text for the "previous" button
      nextText: "Next",       // String: Text for the "next" button
      maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
      navContainer: "",       // Selector: Where controls should be appended to, default is after the 'ul'
      manualControls: "",     // Selector: Declare custom pager navigation
      namespace: "rslides",   // String: Change the default namespace used
      before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
      after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
    });
    </script>
```

I first thought there was conflict with my mobile menu but by removing it theres still no joy? By placing the JS up beneath the image list it kills off the mobile menu behaviour? I am a little stuck?

Comment: @Abhidev - I have fixed that issue by going through each bit of my code: I have a new issue: Hi guys,

I am using `http://responsiveslides.com/`as my chosen image slider. I have added a static div overlaying the slider - was wondering if there is a way to add a div to each slide so when it scrolls around the content in that div changes with the image?

Comment: @Abhidev I have stripped it down but here is my code:

    <div style="heigt: 500px;">
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
           <li><img src="img/businessbig.jpg" alt="" ></li>
          <li><img src="img/cateringbig.jpg" alt=""></li>
          <li><img src="img/nurseriesbig.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
    
     </div>

Comment: @Abhidev      
     
     
       <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="welcome">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    <br />
    <p>fhsdlfhsjfhskdjfhsjkdfhsjkdfhkjd</p>
    <br />
    <p>sjflksdfjklsdfjsldjflksdjfklsdjflksdjflks</p>
    <br />
    <p>jfhsjkfhsdkjfhksjdfhksjdhfksdhfksdhk</p> 
     </div>


So for my class welcome to sit on top of the image slider as it does nicely as it is but for the content within that to change as the slider rolls around?

Comment: it will be better if you add this in jsfiddle

Comment: @Abhidev so here the http://jsfiddle.net/7qe83/ the images arnt scrolling because there some files missing but you get the idea.